# Determine where the function $f(z)=\operatorname{Log}(z^3+2i)$ is analytic.

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, analyticity

I need to know if my intuition is correct here.

Idea: I would use De'Moivre's formula to find all third roots of -2i and exclude one of these rays because these are the values that give $z^3+2i=0$ and $\operatorname{Log}(z)$ is not defined at $0$, hence not analytic at $0$. Given that the third roots of $-2i$ are, $2^{\frac{1}{3}}[\cos(\frac{-\pi}{2}+\frac{2k\pi}{3})+i\sin(\frac{-\pi}{2}+\frac{2k\pi}{3})]$ for $k=0,1,2$. Then pick a cut of principal branch say $k=0$ and say the function is analytic of the set $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{re^{i\theta}:\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}\}$.

Comment: Assuming that $\operatorname{Log}$ means the principal branch, you're on the right track, but you're not quite there. The function  $f$ will be analytic on the set where $z^3+2i$ is *not* negative real.

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/483135/find-a-branch-of-fz-logz3-2-that-is-analytic-at-z-0/483186#483186) for a related problem.

Comment: @mrf, so i need to delete all these ray given by the third root of -2i